# allocate memory in C

Tags: c

As I know in C :

a. Global and static variables locate at data segment

b. When a function is called, memory is allocated on the stack to hold
parameter values, local variables, and the address of the calling
function

c. the struct is aligned based on the greatest alignment requirement
of it's members.

I want to know what these base on to define?
Are there some manual or book about these?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1eFfza3

Comment: what do you mean with "I want to know what these base on to define?" ?

Comment: I want to know what(manual) complier(gcc) allocate memory in C according to

Answer (score 2):

These are mainly implementation details, so best to consult your C compiler's manual/documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to know about memory layout of C executable for gcc. I think this will help a bit. [Memory layout in C](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/)

Comment: why are the global variables and static variables put into Initialized Data Segment? according to ABI?

Answer (score 0):

These are all purely implementation details; there's no guarantee that you even *have* a data segment, nor is there a guarantee that all function parameters are passed via the stack (they may be passed via registers).

This is determined by the processor architecture (x86, SPARC, MIPS, PA-RISC, Power) and to some extent by the operating system, so you would want to start with developer's guides for the architecture you're interested in, such as [Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Answer (score 0):

Compiler documentation. Also a good breakdown on how everything works behind the curtain is any book on x86 Assembly. Some compilers allow inline assembly in their C code, so you can try to rewrite some C code in assembly to see if you can match what the compiler is doing. It should provide you with working knowledge of the stack, alignments etc.